# Detect when the selenium webdriver changes url in browser

Tags: c#, webdriver

I need to detect when the url in the browser changes whether it was because of click on a link, a form post or I changed the url in code.

I need it because I'm creating an object to represent the page and I need to dispose recreate it when the url changes.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
private string _pageUrl;
protected T _page = default(T);
protected T Page
{
    get
    {
        if (_page == null || UrlHasChanged())
        {
            _page = GetPage<T>();
            SetPageUrl();
        }
        return _page;
    }
}

private bool UrlHasChanged()
{
    var driver = Session.GetDriver();
    return driver.Url != _pageUrl;
}

public void SetPageUrl()
{
    _pageUrl = Session.GetDriver().Url;
}
```

This works in most cases but it fails when the test goes forward a page and then goes back to the initial page.

I need a way to detect when the url changes so I can reset the _page field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a Java developer, so, I search in the C# documentation what looked similar to the Java API. I think you should use the EventFiringWebDriver :

```
EventFiringWebDriver firingDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
firingDriver.NavigatingBack += new EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs>(...);
firingDriver.NavigatedBack += new EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs>(...);
firingDriver.NavigatingForward += new EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs>(...);
firingDriver.NavigatedForward += new EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs>(...);
```

I looked at the unit tests and I found this one that may be useful for you : 
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dotnet/test/WebDriver.Support.Tests/Events/EventFiringWebDriverTest.cs

Comment: I think this won't work when the URL has changed after eg. clicking a link/button.

Comment: EventFiringWebDriver sadly only functions whey you explicitly call the Navigate() method

Comment: @HappyBird have you found a solution for that?

Comment: @garryman you are free to implement more listener methods which may lead to URL change, such as `NavigateTo`, `ClickOn`, `ChangeValueOf`, etc. This will handle mouse clicks as well as key strokes.